# SQL join tables with conditions to only show Max

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join tableA and tableB on UniqueID however I only want to join on the latest Date in tableA with certain Status restrictions (Not in S). I know I need to use the Max functions however I can't get it to work. How do I get the result table below?

I was thinking of something like:

```
Select
    tableA.UniqueID,
    MAX(tableA.Date),
    tableA.Status,
    tableB.Col1
    From tableA 
Inner join tableB on (tableB.UniqueID = tableA.UniqueID and tableA.Status = 'A')`

tableA:

| UniqueID | Date                 | Status |
| -------- | -------------------  |--------|
| 123      | 2015-07-05  00:00:00 | S      |
| 123      | 2015-07-06  00:00:00 | S      |
| 123      | 2015-07-07  00:00:00 | A      |

and tableB:

| UniqueID | Col1 |
| -------- | -    |
| 123      | X    |
| 125      | Y    |
| 126      | Z    |

Result table:

| UniqueID | Date                 | Status | Col1|
| -------- | -------------------  |--------|---- |
| 123      | 2015-07-07  00:00:00 | A      | X   |
```

Comment: Please show the SQL you wrote that isn't producing the expected output.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: added what I had in my post

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways -

```
  select
    t_a.*, t_b.*
  from 
    table_b t_b 
    join 
    (
      select 
        uniqueid, date, status,
        rank() over (partition by uniqueid order by date desc ) rank_
      from
        table_a
    ) t_a on t_b.uniqueid = t_a.uniqueid 
  where
    t_a.rank_ = 1
  ;
```

fiddle url : (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06660177b6c116a811218863ce428985)